# Elasticseach & Kibana - best practice for visualizing one year's logs

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using ElasticSearch with Kibana to store and visualize data from my logs. I know it is customary to use Logstash, but I just use the elasticsearch Rest API and POST new elements to it.

I am trying to look for best practices in terms of how I should manage my indices, given I have about 50k logs per day, and I want to visualize sometimes weekly, sometimes monthly and sometimes yearly data. And also I have no need for more than one node. I don't need a high available cluster.

So I am basically trying to determine:
-How should I store my indexes, by time? Monthly? Weekly? One index for everything?
-What are the disadvantages of a huge index (one index that contains all my data)? Does it mean that the entire index is in memory?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like to match indexes to the data retention policy.  Daily indexes work very well for log files, so you can expire one day's worth after X days of retention.

The fewer indexes/shards you have, the less RAM is used in overhead by Elasticsearch to manage them.

The mapping for a field is frozen when the field is added to the index.  With a daily index, I can update the mapping and have it take effect for the new indexes, and wait for the old ones to expire.  With a longer-term indexes, you'd probably need to reindex the data, which I always try to avoid.

The settings for shards and replicas are also frozen when you create the index.

You can visualize them in Kibana regardless of how they're stored.  Use the @timestamp field as your X-axis and change the "interval" to the period you want.

Using logstash would be important if you wanted to alter your logs at all.  We do a lot of normalization and creation of new fields, so it's very helpful.  If it's not a requirement for you, you might also look into filebeats, which can write directly to elasticsearch.

Lots to consider...

Comment: Great, Thanks. Do shards have any meaning if I don't need high-availability? Do shards help make search more efficient somehow?

Comment: Do you mean that I should POST the log messages as:
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/log-15March2016/log -d '{@timestamp:..., ...}'

Comment: And then should I visualize using log-* (with wildcards)?
Why is a huge index bad?

Comment: Your index must have at least one shard (that's where the data is!).  With one node, you wouldn't need replica shards.  If you add more nodes down the road, the additional shards can be searched in parallel, though then the results must be combined.

Comment: As mentioned in the answer, more frequent indexes allow you to change the mappings or shard settings more easily.

Comment: Yes, but will I be able to visualize a year's data?

Comment: Kibana will query elasticsearch for whatever date range you give it.  Kibana even includes "Last 5 years" as a selection (assuming you've loaded that much data, of course).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106358/discussion-between-user967710-and-alain-collins).